# Private Demos and Betas in Apple App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

How is it possible to submit an app to the AppStore which is not for general use? For instance I might want to do an invite-only free trial before making the app generally available for a fee.

Or I might want to be able to give free copies to specific people for promotion. Are these kind of things possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an ad-hoc distribution.

It's all detailed very well in the iOS developer center, it's what you need to use for beta testing, etc.

Comment: The issue there is it's not the same app as the 'real' one when it goes live, is it? I was wondering if iOS supported activation keys or something like that, or Apple would allow me to put up password-protected apps.

Comment: You don't put them up, you distribute them to your testers via a bundle that you create and they load via iTunes (IIRC - it's been a while since I've done it).  You need to know some information about their phone, etc.  Check the developers center under ad-hoc distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin's answered your first question: with regards to your second (giving free copies for promotion) - you can generate promotional codes once you've uploaded your app through iTunes Connect. You're allowed (I believe) to generate up to one hundred codes - this counter is reset every time you update your app.